# Zend Rest is so slow on the stagging server

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, rest

I've deployed a project in the staging server and experienced issues regarding the Zend_Rest. I created a simple test service that should return "hello world" on the calling script. The call would take approx. 4secs to finish. It is really slow given the simple task. Any suggestions for optimization?

here's some code snippets :

// $url  is a connetion to a resful controller

> $client = new
>   Zend_Rest_Client($url);   $response =
>   $client->printHelloWorld()->post(); 
>   echo
>   $response->printHelloWorld->response;

Server controller has :

> ```
> public function getAction()
> {
>     $server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
>     $server->setClass('Webservice_User');
>     $server->handle();
> }
> ```

Comment: Seems like there may be something else going on beyond the Zend Framework. Have you had a chance to run a profile and see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Yes, I've fixed some routes and drop it to 2secs. But I guess 2 secs is still long for a simple webservice call.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what your application is doing? Are you using Zend_Rest to connect to another web service, or are you using it as a server for other applications to connect to?

Comment: I'm using it as a client. I created a controller that would use the Zend_Rest_Client($server url) then call a hello world function.The process takes 2secs to finish. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I guess I will not be using zend rest for the application. Zend_Rest examples around the web has an RPC implementation which is really heavy because of the reflection process. I was able to drop it more but decided that webservice is not the right way for the special process that I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install APC or any other PHP accelerator, Zend is really heavy
2. Bench server controller separately (ab -c 10 -t 10 http://sdfklsdf) to isolate issue on server/client.

Answer (score 0):

at your server :

1. don't write server at controller. write it at index.php / other file
2. use just a simple bootstrap
3. don't include any unimportant zend library class

ex (index.php) :

```
set_include_path(
    implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
        get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
     APPLICATION_ENV,
     APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'    
);

$application->bootstrap();    

$server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
$server->setClass('Webservice_User');
$server->handle();
```